# Responce.Write to divID

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, string

I know javascript and I am learning ASP.NET C#

What I want to do(done is javascript):

```
          document.getElementById('divID-1').innerHTML= '<p>Wrong Password</p>';
```

I need to make a statement equivalent to the javascript one but in ASP.NET C#

When I do

```
         Response.Write('Wrong Password');
```

It writes it to a spot that is covered by my navbar. I have to go into inspect element to see it.(Pain in the butt.)

If I could just write it to a visible or a specific DIV that would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
<div id="MyDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

You must have the runat="server" attribute in your DIV tag. Then it becomes a server side control. Thus you'll be able to call it by it's ID as follows in your code behind.

```
MyDiv.InnerText = Response.Write('Wrong Password');
```

All the best learning ASP.Net and C#